# Finding the period of the signal in python

Tags: python, numpy, signals, signal-processing, period

I'm newly learning and practicing python. My question is, how can find the period of the signal through the python? And in which different ways?

````
"A periodic signal (but only ploted on a bounded interval)"

signal1=np.exp(np.sin(20*np.pi*t)*np.sin(30*np.pi*t))
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t,signal1);```
````

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  This is far too broad for Stack Overflow.  There are Fourier Transform functions you can find with a simple browser search -- which we expect before you post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,  I guess that is not a really easy question as it may seem because not all functions are periodic, you can use [np.fft.fft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html) like this:

```
plt.plot(np.abs(np.fft.fft(signal1)))
```

[image]

This is the graph of the frequencies of this particular signal.

Answer (score 0):

A Fourier Transform outputs the frequencies of the sinusoidal components of a signal. Unless the signal is pure, i.e., consists of only one sinusoidal, you are not guaranteed to get the periods from an fft.

For example: let f(t) = sin(2*pi*t/4) + sin(2*pi*t/6), a sum of two sine waves with periods 4 and 6. In that case, the period of f(t) is the Least Common Multiple of the two periods, namely 12.

Hence, you are indeed looking for [autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation).